# create a div and place it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create some divs and place the around the body. That means left , right, up and down. I create a div every time a client connect via socket. and here is the code

```
var parent = document.getElementById("#parent-div")
socket.on("isConnected", function(data) {
    // Receive the 'data' and check if 'isConnected' is true

    if(data.isConnected == true) {
       parent.innerHTML += "<div class='new-div'></div>"
    }
});
```

and here is the style of the div :

```
.ZE {
    position: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:  #73AD81;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px 60px;
    border: 2px solid #965D31;
}
```

how can i do that ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you meant by "place the around the body" ? Also, you have declared a css which is not being used in your code.

Comment: on the right , left , up and down the screen. The css is the style of the div that i want to create !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work as you have it once you've made a few adjustments.

**[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/ssctuwkz/)**

First, you have a number symbol (`#`) you don't need in your `getElementById()`:

Should be:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent-div");
```

Next, create classes for the locations you want to place them in:

```
.ZE.left {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.ZE.right  {
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.ZE.up {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.ZE.down {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Up to you how you place them. Above is just one way to place them left/right/top/bottom and may not be the best way at that but I've based it on your existing code.

Lastly you'll want to add those classes, incrementally, or otherwise in your callback function:

```
// for demo purposes
var data = {
    isConnected: true
},
    classes = ['left', 'right', 'up', 'down'];

//socket.on("isConnected", function(data) {
// Receive the 'data' and check if 'isConnected' is true

// loop for demo purposes
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    if(data.isConnected === true) {
       parent.innerHTML += "<div class='ZE " + classes[i] + "'></div>"
    }

}
//});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("div_to_place_within");

    parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);

    newDiv.id = "some_id";
    newDiv.className = "some classnames";
```

createElement & appendChild

Comment: you didn't anwser my question , how can i place them in the correct location ?